# Give each user a custom page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how I could give each user a custom page like on YouTube where they have YouTube.com/users/Username

My approach would be to modify an .htaccess file so if I had www.domain.com/cgi-bin/user.py?username=x, and someone wrote in the url www.domain.com/users/x, it would direct them to that page above. I'm just not sure exactly how to write an .htaccess to meet that criteria.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /cgi-bin/user\.py\?username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /users/%2\? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)\$ /cgi-bin/user.py?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured it out myself.